# Has Windows Web Server 2008 Plesk Inside By Default Or Not?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I bought a vps and when I connect to it I saw plesk and mail enable installed.
Are `Plesk` and `MailEnable` for windows web server 2008 installed as default or does DataCenter have installed them individually?

Comment: Your VPS providor would have installed Plesk - no way would Plesk "come" with Server 2008 editions.

Comment: Jesus, i think the second one was me...

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Plesk is not a Microsoft product.

Please point questions like these over to your service provider if you are having difficulties finding out stuff like this with - let's say - google.